# CRM Dynamics Email a link of current view. ViewId?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

Which table/s holds the **viewId** that is found in the hyperlink generated when clicking on "COPY A LINK - Of Current View"

e.g. Active Accounts        https://mycrm/dev/main.aspx?etc=1&extraqs=%3fpagemode%3diframe%26sitemappath%3dCS%257cCustomers%257cnav_accts&pagetype=entitylist&viewid=%7b00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001002%7d&viewtype=1039

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System views are stored inside SavedQuery

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg594431.aspx

User views (saved from Advanced Find) are stored inside UserQuery

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509053.aspx